# PIC32MX470F512L not appearing on harmony setup?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab, mplab-harmony

I installed Harmony plugin in MPLAB X IDE because i can't put this pic working with MCC.

I was going to do a new project for this pic and when i was going to select it, it doesn't appear on the list! anyone with this problem?

[image: rmony]

Using:
-MPLAB Harmony Configurator 3 (v3.3.0.1)

-MPLAB X IDE v5.05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like MPLAB harmony v3 is a new beast and the PIC32MX470F512L files were only added about a month ago.

1. First make sure you download the latest framework when starting a new project by clicking on "Launch Framework Downloader" whilst online
2. Browse for a path you want the files to download to. click on Create  Folder if it says that the path is not valid.
3. click next until it downloads the catalog.
4. Select packages required
5. Click on Download and next only when downloaded
6. Make sure the Framework path is now the same path as the one you chose to download the packages in.
7. Click next
8. enter project name, the next
9. select your PIC.

If you are still having trouble, I'd use MPLAB Harmony v2 which you can install separately from MPLAB harmony v3 in my version of MPLAB 5.15

[image: MPLAB Harmony v2]

MPLAB Harmony v2 supports your desired PIC

[image: MPLAB Harmony v2 (2)]

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it, after i can access it on MPLAB, it says path is not valid.

Comment: I updated the answer for harmony v3. did you try redownloading framework ? It comes up with a few "invalid" path errors, but these are mainly for download folders that you can create yourself, or just by clicking on the "create folder" button if one appears.